# Is it correct to write a code to pass data to child component in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a question.
I use vue.js with defineComponent.

I want to get data and pass the data to child components but the data is undefined.

**parent**

```js
<template>
  <Child :data="user"/>
  <div>{{ user.name }}</div> <!-- It works here -->
</template>

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const user = ref({});
    const getData = () => {
      // takes 3 seconds
      user.value = data;
    }
    return {user}
  }
})
```

**child**

```js
<template>
  <div>{{ user.name }}</div> <!-- TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined -->
</template>

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    data: { type: Object },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const user = ref(props.data);
    return {user}
  }
})
```

If I use watch in child component, It works.
Is it correct to write a code like this?

**child**

```js
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    data: { type: Object },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const user = ref({});
    watch(props, (n, o) => user.value = props.data)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, your `user` variable is filled in asynchronously, so in the beginning you're sending an empty object as the prop. That said, it shouldn't fail since `{}.name` will return `undefined` and not throw an error.

You have several ways to handle an empty prop in your components:

1. Create the child component only when you have the full data available:

```html
<Child v-if="user" :data="user" />
```

This has the benefit to be performant: you don't ever execute the Child component code until you have the user.

2. You handle the empty prop within the Child component

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="!data">Loading...</div>
  <div v-else>
    {{ data.name }}
  </div>
</template>
```

This allows you to show something when the data is missing.

---

Note: you don't have to copy the `props.data` into a `ref` inside your component unless you want to mutate it. If you do that, you have to use a watcher to update your inner `user` ref whenever the prop changes too, otherwise the Child component data will be outsynced with the `data` prop.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, as you have 3 seconds to fetch data this approach is right.

The issue is that the child component is trying to access the data before it is actually available. This is because the `getData()` function in the parent component takes 3 seconds to complete and during that time, the `user` object is still empty. When the child component is created, it tries to access the `user` object before it has been populated with data, as a result you are getting an error.